# ASP.Net MVC: How to attach unobtrusive validation message to controls

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, validation

instead of showing validation message i want to attach validation message to controls title attribute and i have done it but tool tip is not showing for title attribute and also red border is not coming when validation is fail.

here i am attaching small sample code which i follow to attach validation message to controls attribute.

```
$("span[class='field-validation-error']").each(function () {

$(this).addClass("hidden");//Add class hidden to hide  @@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.xyz) if using bootstrap , else use css
            var inputID = $(this).attr("data-valmsg-for");//get the id of the input field for which this validation prompted
            var validationMessage = $(this).html();//Get validation message for input filed which is prompted          
            //$("#" + inputID).tooltip({ 'trigger': 'hover', 'title': validationMessage });//Trigger the tooltip now, if using bootstrap.

                      //******OR*******

            $("#" + inputID).attr("title",validationMessage);
              });           
        }
        return false;
    });
```

my full jquery and mvc code is in dotnet fiddle whose link is https://dotnetfiddle.net/30YQEX

so please some one check the code and discuss with me what i made wrong there?

1) why tooltip is not coming when hover mouse on control which causes validation fail?

2) why red border is not coming when validation is getting fail ?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your `$("span[class='field-validation-error']").each ...` code is executed when the page is opened. Instead it should be executed after validation occurred. Only then the error css class will be applied on the controls.

The best approach for this, is to override the jQuery Validate default events:

```
$.validator.setDefaults({
    highlight: function (element) {
        $(element).   //do your custom error displaying here
    },
    unhighlight: function (element) {
        //hide your custom error here
    },
    ignore: [],
});
```

Comment: the code you have given me is that a small snippet and from the snip the concept is not coming to my mind what to add inside `highlight: function ` ? can u please add my js code in `highlight: function `